# Centrifugal force on spinning black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, centrifugal-force, kerr-metric

I saw the term spinning black hole popping up everywhere so my question do spinning black hole behave similarly to say a planet where it bulge in the equatorial and compress at the poles? what fundamental force is causing the bulging because in the case of planet it is the electrostatic force?

Comment: Equatorial bulging of rotating planets is not from electrostatic force.

Comment: @G.Smith: I meant to say that when planet spins the momentum is carry away to the equator by electrons

Comment: No, it isn’t. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @G.Smith: binding energy is result from gravitational force and when planet spin there is a centrifugal force pushing outward and this force transfer from atoms to atoms via electrostatic force no? I know it is the inertial but I can't visualize that.

Comment: Electrostatic repulsion between atoms keeps the planet from collapsing under gravity. Is that what you're talking about? But to calculate the equatorial bulge due to centrifigual force, you don’t have to think about inter-atomic forces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular momentum of a Kerr or Kerr-Newman black hole causes the event horizon to have an equatorial bulge. It emerges from solving the Einstein field equations for gravity and has nothing to do with any of the other three fundamental forces.

You can picture it as being similar to the bulging of a rotating planet due to centrifugal force.

Comment: I thought is was ringularity because point cannot spin so obvious I was deeply mistaken.

Comment: Point particles can have angular momentum in the form of quantum spin.

Comment: The angular momentum of the black hole is simply equal to the angular momentum of the matter and radiation that first creates and later falls into the hole. Angular momentum must be conserved.